# Returning a partial IEnumerable (Elements generated prior to exception)

Tags: c#

I'm working with an image utility designed to map a directory of vendor files into my company's file schema. Each vendor image may have multiple pages, which we don't support. I have a top level method that grabs an ID from the database and uses it to determine the new file's directory and name. Next, it splits the multi-page image and saves each one to our directories. If an error is encountered, the issue is logged and any created files are removed:

```
public void TransferImagesToTargetDirectoryUsingSMLLCNaming()
    {
            IEnumerable<string> newfilepaths = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                image.ImageName = MergeImageInDatabase(image);
                newfilepaths = SaveImage(image);
            }
            catch
            {
                LogFailedImage(image);
                foreach (string filepath in newfilepaths)
                {
                    File.Delete(filepath);
                }
            }
      }
```

The SaveImage code:

```
    private IEnumerable<string> SaveImage(SmllcImage image)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < image.SourceImages.Count; i++)
        {
            string newfilepath = "some file path";

            image.SourceImages[i].Save(newfilepath);

            yield return newfilepath;
        }
    }
```

In the event of an exception, I hoped I could have a list of whatever files were created up until the error, then handle the cleanup in the catch block of the calling method. Unfortunately, this implementation doesn't work - any exception apparently causes the yield return statement to return an empty collection.

Is it possible to return a "partial" collection from a method, containing whatever elements were added prior to any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If exception is thrown from `SaveImage` then `newfilepaths` will retain the value that it had before entering the function (empty list).

If you want to populate the list as the function is running then `SaveImage` must have additional parameter (the list) and return `void`, and then if exception is thrown the list will have all the items that it was populated with.

```
private void SaveImage(SmllcImage image, List<string> theList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < image.SourceImages.Count; i++)
    {
        string newfilepath = "some file path";

        image.SourceImages[i].Save(newfilepath);

        theList.Add(newfilepath);
    }
}
```

I actually wonder if your current code actually creates any image in the directory. Files should not be created when `SaveImage` is executed, but when the result is enumerated, which is never in current code.

Comment: Glad I wasn't the only one questioning whether or not the `Save` is actually invoked at the point. If any exception occurred at the point, I would expect it to be the call above (`MergeImageInDatabase(image)`). And with an empty `catch`, there's no indication of what had an exception.